# Is there a method to dynamically calculate bin ranges so that record counts are equivalent for all bins (Excel)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I work with higher education data and my company is looking for a way to automate bin sizing. We receive individual records of students and their GPA, and "rank" them accordingly. MRE:

| GPA Points | Record Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 130 |
| 1.0 | 200 |
| 2.0 | 480 |
| 3.0 | 27 |
| 4.0 | 100 |
| 5.0 | 59 |
| Total: | 997 |

Is there a way to automatically shift the "GPA Points" so that the amount in "Record Count" is about equal for all bins? This would need to be done through Excel, as my work operates with Access, Excel, and Tableau.

Please let me know what you think!

I've tried Sorting algorithms, Visual aids (histograms), and manual sorting. These options work fine, but they're time consuming and sometimes difficult when a university has a 100-point scale GPA.

Comment: Shouldn't there be another column: grades? Also what have you tried. What is the expected (close) results?

Comment: If these are bin ranges as defined in the Frequency function, it would imply that 130 students got exactly zero, 200 got (say) 0.1 up to 1 etc. Am I right in assuming that an individual student can get something like 3.9 GPA points (i.e. it doesn't need to be a whole number?) I think it's quite tricky because it could/should approximate to a normal distribution so you would need a non-linear adjustment.

Comment: I’m assuming you already know this, but to clarify, there’s no way to do it with the data shown…  Knowing that there are 200 students between 1.0 and 1.99 tells us nothing about the distribution of students in that range.  There may be stat functions that do what yu want, but my simplistic take is this.  I think your first bin top boundary ends up being `=SMALL(scores,COUNT(scores)/5)`.  Your second bin top score ends up being `=SMALL(scores,2*COUNT(scores)/5)`. This continues 3*, 4*, and finally `=LARGE(scores,1)` for the top of the top bin.  “scores” is when range containing the scores.